# .Net not triggering Javascript on search (?) - should ignore default value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Issue: When I use *btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click, btnSearchTop.Click* the code works perfectly and ignores any 'shown' values that there by default to help users i.e. in the 'street' box it says 'street'.

However when I run *btnRiskRating_Click(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)* it being in these values so I end up with a search that has the values in (if I then hit 'btnSearch_Click' it works correctly). I assume it's something to so with the e As part but it's not my strong point at all! If you need the javascript I can pop that too.

There are two 'search' buttons as one is a 'quick link' essentially as 80-90% of the time in this internal website case it's all they need.

```
Protected Sub btnRiskRating_Click(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)

        Dim vRiskRating As String = Trim(e.CommandArgument.ToString())

        Session.Item("sRiskRating") = vRiskRating.ToString

        With oAuditData
            .EventType = "LOG"
            .EventDescription = "User clicked Risk Rating  " & vRiskRating.ToString & ""
            .PemcoModule = "All"
            .SiteID = 0
            .UserID = CInt(oUser.UserID)
            .EmployeeID = Session("EmployeeID")
        End With
        oAudit.WriteAuditTrailItem(oAuditData)


        Call PrcSearch()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click, btnSearchTop.Click

        Call PrcSearch()

    End Sub

    Public Sub PrcSearch()

        Session.Item("sUPRN") = Trim(sUPRN.Text)
        Session.Item("sStreet") = Trim(sStreet.Text)
        Session.Item("sSurveyCompany") = Trim(sSurveyCompany.Text)
        Session.Item("sPostcode") = Trim(sPostcode.Text)
        Session.Item("sPropertyName") = Trim(sPropertyName.Text)
        Session.Item("sDateFrom") = sDateFrom.Text
        Session.Item("sDateTo") = sDateTo.Text

        Dim vSearch As String

        vSearch = Trim(sUPRN.Text) & " - " & Trim(sSurveyCompany.Text) & " - " & Trim(sPostcode.Text)
        vSearch = vSearch & " - " & Trim(sPropertyName.Text) & " - "
        '& Trim(sDateFrom.Text) & " - " & Trim(sDateTo.Text)

        With oAuditData
            .EventType = "LOG"
            .EventDescription = "User searched " & vSearch & ""
            .PemcoModule = "All"
            .SiteID = 0
            .UserID = CInt(oUser.UserID)
            .EmployeeID = Session("EmployeeID")
        End With
        oAudit.WriteAuditTrailItem(oAuditData)

        Call PrcActionsCSVReport()

        With oAuditData
            .EventType = "LOG"
            .EventDescription = "User search CSV created " & vSearch & ""
            .PemcoModule = "All"
            .SiteID = 0
            .UserID = CInt(oUser.UserID)
            .EmployeeID = Session("EmployeeID")
        End With
        oAudit.WriteAuditTrailItem(oAuditData)
    End Sub
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

               $('input.Date').datepicker({
                   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                   changeMonth: true,
                   changeYear: true,
                   numberOfMonths: 2,
                   defaultDate: "0w"
               });

               function showMore() {
                   $('div.Search div.Filter ul.More').slideDown(500);
                   $('div.Search div.Filter span.Right').text('Show less search options');
               }
               function hideMore() {
                   $('div.Search div.Filter ul.More').slideUp(500);
                   $('div.Search div.Filter span.Right').text('Show more search options');
               }

               $('div.Search div.Filter span.Right').on('click', function () {

                   if ($(this).text() == 'Show more search options')
                       showMore();
                   else
                       hideMore();
               });

               $('input.Validate').on('focusin', function () {
                   if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))
                       $(this).val('');
               });

               $('input.Validate').on('focusout', function () {
                   $(this).validate();
                   if ($(this).val() == '')
                       $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
               });

               $('form').on('submit', function () {
                   var error = false;

                   // Validate all the fields just to be sure
                   $('input.Validate').each(function () {
                       var val = $(this).val();
                       if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))
                           $(this).val('');
                       if (!$(this).validate())
                       {
                           alert($(this).attr('name'));
                           error = true;
                       }
                       $(this).val(val);
                   });

                   // If there was an error don't submit data
                   if (error) return false;

                   $('input.Validate').each(function () {
                       if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))
                           $(this).val('');
                   });
               });

           });
```

Comment: Its not JavaScript its VB

Comment: Scrap last comment, this is what happens when I try and help people with non related JavaScript problems :(

Comment: My thought process was that it was not firing because Javascript might not recognize the e As CommandEventArgs for example

Comment: Updated title, hopefully makes more sense!

Comment: Added JS to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found we had a javascript code that worked only on btnSearch trigger but this has been amended now.